# Xamarin.Forms ToolbarItems Title

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is it possible to to disable title of current page in toolbarItems?

https://imgur.com/a/MsX0FKp

```
    <ToolbarItem Text="{Binding positionNumber}"
                 />
    <ToolbarItem Text="PREV"
                 Clicked="previousQuestion"/>
    <ToolbarItem Text="HINT"
                 />
    <ToolbarItem Text="NEXT"
                 Clicked="nextQuestion"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

I've achieved it by simply adding 
 ToolbarItem Text=" 'space' PREV"
is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: set the page title to blank, or use a custom TitleView

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot I believe that one is dead or clarify.